# spawnUri() with "https"

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am trying to dynamically load code from files hosted in a HTTPS server.

Has anyone successfully made use of spawnUri() with `https://` URIs?
I have tested and it works fine with `http://` URIs.

But with `https://` I keep getting:

```
Not a known scheme: https://example.com/MyIsolate.dart
#0      _filePathFromUri (dart:_builtin:289)
#1      _loadDataAsync (dart:_builtin:359)'
Stack Trace:
#0      Isolate.spawnUri (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:256)
...
...
```

I wonder if I am missing something.

for eg, you can simply try this code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

ReceivePort receivePort;

main() {
  receivePort = new ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawnUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/MyIsolate.dart"), null, receivePort.sendPort);
}
```

My Dart VM version is 1.6.0 on macos_x64

EDIT:
Parsing the uri string using Uri.parse() before passing it to spawnUri as an argument. (As pointed out by @user568109)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume its caused by this bug which was fixed a few days ago http://dartbug.com/20837

Answer (score 2):

It takes a Uri object, so parse it before passing:

```
Isolate.spawnUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/MyIsolate.dart"), null, sendPort);
```

I believe scheme is the [protocol](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html) which it takes by default to be `http`. So for other protocols you have to give it explicitly. It is better to convert it to `Uri` always. `Uri` is in `core` library.

Comment: You are right about parsing, and I forgot it while creating this example... But I did parse it and test it. Still I get the same exception. Which makes me wonder if it is a bug?
I'll give you a +1 for finding the error in code, but cannot accept the answer as it does not solve the problem :)